# Activating Serial console in AOSP based Tinkerboard 2 platform

Tags: android, console, android-source

I am using AOSP to do some projects with TinkerBoard2 board. I have a problem enabling the serial console input. I have changed kernel command line arguments in order to ovveride console as such:

```
console=ttyS2,115200 androidboot.console=ttyS2,115200
```

Now I am able to see output in /dev/ttyS2 while device boots. However, there is no single user login (console opening) on that TTY. I have an idea what to do in Linux, but for Android don't have much understanding how to open up this console. I have came across following documentation that is written for another Android board, but this mostly seem unapplicable to my case:

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-shamu-3.10-lollipop-mr1/Documentation/serial-console.txt

What I found also from TinkerBoard2 sources how console for ADB is opened:

```
on fs && property:ro.debuggable=1
    start console

service console /system/bin/sh
    console
    disabled
    seclabel u:r:shell:s0
```

Any guidance is appreciated. How do I add a console for /dev/ttyS2 for this Android board? Is getty usable for Android platforms?
Thanks